# How can a script be used either as a command line application or as a module

Tags: python, command-line, argparse

I feel like this should be obvious but I have been googling a lot about this and I haven't come across a solutions yet so I would appreciate any help here if you could:

I wrote a python script that I want to be able to use as a command line application but also as a module that I can load in other applications. So far, I only wrote code for the command line options. Here's a summary of how my file etl.py is structured:

```
import os
import re
import sys
import shlex
import argparse
import itertools
import subprocess
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text
# other imports here...

def etl(argv):
    """
    ETL function for rasters ...
    # more doc here
    """
    args = parser.parse_args(argv)
    d = vars(args)

    os.chdir(d.get("root_dir"))
    files = [f for f in os.listdir(".") for p in d.get("products") if p in f]

    # a) Reprojection (option "r")
    if d.get("which") == "r":
        for f in files:
            ofile = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(d.get("reproj_dir"), f))
            if os.path.exists(ofile):
                if d.get("overwrite") is True:
                    gdutil.reproject(os.path.abspath(f), ofile,    .get("proj"))
                else:
                    print("{}: File already exists. skipping".format(ofile))
            else:
                gdutil.reproject(os.path.abspath(f), ofile, d.get("proj"))
          print("All files reprojected into EPSG {}".format(d.get("proj")))

    # b) Merge (option "m")
    if d.get("which") == "m":
        # more operations here until...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description="""
        'Extract, Transform, Load' script for rasters ...""",
        formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter)
    parser.add_argument("-dir", help="""
        directory containing the input rasters to process

        default value is the current directory""",
        dest="root_dir", default=os.getcwd(), const=os.getcwd(), nargs="?", metavar="DIR")
    gen_opts = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
    gen_opts.add_argument("-p", help="""
        product type(s) to process

        default is to process all products in DIR.           

        """.format(os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])),
        dest="products", nargs="*", metavar="PROD")

    # more gen_opts arguments here

    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
    parser_r = subparsers.add_parser("r", help="""
        reproject rasters into target reprojection

        if rasters corresponding to the passed arguments are found, they will be
        reprojected into the target spatial reference system as defined by
        the passed EPSG code

        reprojected files will have the same pixel resolution as the input
        rasters

        resampling method is nearest neighbor     

        reprojected files are saved to the folder specified with option -r_dir
        or to its default value if missing
        """.format(os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])),
        parents=[gen_opts, overw_opts])
    parser_r.add_argument("proj", help="""
        EPSG code of the destination reprojection""",
        type=int, metavar="EPSG_CODE")

    # more parser_r arguments here

    parser_r.set_defaults(which="r")
    parser_m = subparsers.add_parser("m", help="""
        merge input rasters into a mosaic

        rasters are merged based on the supplied level

        all files that are included in a merge must have the same projection,
        pixel size, no-data value, and be unique in space. otherwise, results
        are not guaranteed""", parents=[gen_opts, group_opt, overw_opts])
    parser_m.add_argument("-m_dir", help="""
        if supplied, the merged rasters will be saved in directory M_DIR

        if not supplied they will be saved to a subfolder named 'merged'
        located at in DIR, or in R_DIR if a reprojection was made in the same
        call""",
        dest="merge_dir", type=str, nargs=1, metavar="M_DIR")
    parser_m.set_defaults(which="m")

    # more parsers and arguments here

    # etl(sys.argv)
    etl(["-dir", "E:\\Data\\Spatial\\soilgrids.org", "r", "3175", "-c", "M"])
```

So far I have only been able to run it with the last line uncommented and calling the script from the terminal with no arguments but that's not the main concern for now.

My question is: how can use the script as a module that I can import in other scripts, e.g. from etl import reproject?

I think one thing will be to put parts of my code (i.e. each section starting with a comment like a) Reprojection, b) Merge, c) ...)  in their own function:

```
def reproject():
    # add code here

def merge():
    # add code here
```

then add default functions to each parser (e.g. parser_r.set_defaults(func=reproject)) but then, how would I define the arguments to each function definition, if I am also to use them from another application in which I would import the module etl, for example:

```
from etl import reproject
reproject() #  arguments?
```

Do I have to add optional arguments or keywords? Do I have to test if arguments can be parsed using parser.parse_args? How would I do that?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the call signature (and the body) of your function

```
def etl(argv):
    ...
```

so that it does not do anything with `argv`.  Instead it will look something like:

```
def etl(products, reproj_dir, ...):
    ...
```

This is called defining the *interface* for your functions.

You can leave all the argument parsing stuff inside of  the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block, but the moment when you call `etl` is when you should use the contents of `sys.argv`.  **You should move the line which calls `parser.parse_args` inside this block, too.**

Looking at the body of the function, it seems to kick into two modes, so indeed it would be best to `def reproject` and `def merge`, and then firm up the interfaces for those, as you were thinking.

Once you have proper interfaces, just import the module and call those functions directly.  The actual functions should not need to know about the command line interface at all.

Comment: thanks for your help. once I called `etl` with the result from `parser.parse_args`, what I'm passing to `etl` is a namespace. what is the standard way of dealing with this inside the function? In the code I posted in my OP, I use a dictionnary created by calling `vars()` on the namespace. Is this the right way? I thought it was possible to use variables in the passed namespace directly by calling their name (e.g. `print(reproj_dir)` but apparently that doesn't work.

Comment: ok I found I need to use `print(args.reproj_dir)` for it to work: is it the standard way to use variables from a passed namespace?

Comment: Yes, that is how you access the variables from the namespace.  It would be better if you pass the individual variables to your functions, rather than passing the whole namespace, because if you want to re-use the functions from within code (as opposed to from a CLI), then you don't want the calling code to have to construct a namespace object to pass in.